# Why does this function return an empty string unless i step over it with the debugger?

Tags: c#

I am working with a Panasonic api. I run the function GetFrameTime() which returns a videos date and time in string format.

It was not working so i debugged the application. if and only if i F10 over the function call line does it return the correct date. all other times it returns an empty string.

```
 string time = _panasonicApiControl.GetFrameTime();
```

I tried placing it in a call every second to see if it was a timing issue, but it never returns anything unless i then place a breakpoint on the line and f10 over it

Nothing in the documentation from the api.

Comment: Do you call this function from different threads?

Comment: Sounds like a race condition somewhere.

Comment: @SomeUser not that I'm aware of. I dont do much with threads so I'm not the most knowledgeable, but no where in my code have i done threading.

Comment: Could you be loading different symbols when you debug?  Do you see a .pdb file for that control?

Comment: How do you know it is a blank string if you don't step over it?  How and where are you checking it in other circumstances?

Comment: it is displayed on the view. no binding errors and shows the string when i place a breakpoint and continue running but then shows blank if i dont have a breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

I found out that problems that does not occur when you are using a breakpoints are most of the times related to threads issues.

My guess is that you are calling this method from different threads without proper synchronization, if _panasonicApiControl object is not natively thread safe (and it is probably not) and you don't create your own sync mechanism around it, using it from multiple threads might cause you getting a weird results (such as empty strings).